# Filtering by distance without using postgis in django-filter

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-orm, django-filter

I've checked some answers related to my question but couldn't find solution.
I have `Foo` and related `FooAddress` models. In django-filter I cannot filter `Foo` by distance, tried many options but no results.
**models.py**

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
   pass

class FooAddress(models.Model):
   foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="address")
   longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
   latitude =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
```

**filters.py**

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from geopy.distance import distance

class FooFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    point = filters.CharFilter(method="filter_by_distance")

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ["is_foo", "is_bar"]

    def filter_by_distance(self, queryset, name, value):
        point = value.split(",")
        if len(point) == 2:
            latitude = float(point[0])
            longitude = float(point[1])
            query_distance = self.data.get("distance")

            queryset = queryset.annotate(
                 distance=distance(
                           (latitude, longitude),
                           (F("address_latitude"), F("address_longitude")) # accepts float or int
                         )
             ).filter(distance__lte=query_distance)

        return queryset
```

In **filters.py** I tried to use geopy's distance method to calculate distance and it accepts float or real number but in my case I am giving `F()` type object that I cannot extract actual field value. Is there any way to figure out this without using postgis ? Or
is it possible to do it with pure PostgreSQL query if yes how can it be done as I am not good at complex SQL queries.  Thanks in advance.